# I want to change the key length in Yahoo Clouse Services Benchmark

Tags: ycsb

I have a very simple requirement:

I need keys of much longer length than what are available in YCSB. I want keys of around 100 to 800 characters as primary keys.

According to this thread, the key length is fixed- it is a concatenation of "user" with an integer.

https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/issues/587

I cannot locate the code where this concatenation is done in ycsb source code.

If I change "User" to another String of 100 characters, or pick one from a predefined set of about 100- it will meet my requirement. But I Cannot locate the line of code that combines the string "User" with a string representation of an Integer.

I have looked through the source code, but just cannot find the line(s) that generate the keys. I found the lines that generate the fields.

Answer (score 1):

please look at [`CoreWorkload.java`](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/yahoo/ycsb/workloads/CoreWorkload.java) and the function - `buildKeyName()`.